# How do I built a static nat from an outside address to an inside address on Cisco?

Tags: cisco, nat

I'm not used to doing NAT on Cisco devices, and I'm tasked with bringing in traffic being sent to a public address that is routed to our gateway.  I would like to NAT the traffic from our gateway (a Cisco 2901 router running IOS 15.0) to a private address.

From what I've read, I think this might work but I have a feeling I'm missing something.

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.1
ip address 63.145.168.58 255.255.255.252
ip nat outside

interface GigabitEthernet0/0.1
ip address 10.2.0.3 255.255.0.0
ip nat inside

ip nat inside source static udp 10.0.1.40 5060 72.165.117.130 5060 extendable
```

72.165.117.130 is one of our private (MPLS) WAN addresses that routes to 63.145.168.58.  I'm trying to forward traffic sent to that address to an internal device at 10.0.1.40.

Is that all there is to creating a one-to-one NAT, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you didn't quite understand the concept of NAT.

NAT means hiding your private IP address(es) behind the public address(es) of your router's external interface; with NAT, you can:

- Have a packet start from one of your internal addresses (10.0.1.40) go outside your network and look to external devices like it originated from your router's external address (63.145.168.58), and
- Have a packet come from outside your network to some port on your router's external IP address (63.145.168.58) and be forwarded by your router to one of your internal addresses (10.0.1.40).

But if a packet is going to some completely different address which is not managed by your router (like 72.165.117.130) and is not passing through the router itself, there's nothing at all the router can do to "intercept" it and forward it to some other destination.

Comment: 72.165.117.130 is managed by the router in question.  It's one of a small block (/29) of addresses being routed to it.

Comment: What do you mean by "managed"? Is it assigned to one of the router's interfaces? You said the router's external interface has the address 63.145.168.58.

Comment: Our ISP is sending traffic destined for 72.165.117.130 to our router.  My understanding is that our router should be able to see these packets and change the destination, which the switches down the line would then be able to get to the device at 10.0.1.40.

Comment: If your router needs to receive and handle packets addressed to 72.165.117.130, it needs either to have that address assigned to one of its interfaces, or to have a route to where that address actually is.

Comment: Hrm, I'm not sure that makes sense to me.  Maybe I'm not explaining the setup well enough.  The ISP is routing a /29 subnet to our router for us to handle (72.165.117.128/29).  Some of those packets will have a destination of 72.165.117.130.  This subnet will route through our router at 63.145.168.58.  You're saying that our router won't be able to translate the destination of these packets to an internal address unless we route them to another device?

Comment: To clarify further, we do the same thing with our web servers.  We have a dozen or so internally, and "assign" each a public address.  That public address block is routed to our router from our ISP, which we route to a SonicWall firewall, and use NAT on the SonicWall to get the public address translated to a private address.  I was looking to do the same thing here, but doing the NAT on the router instead (since a firewall isn't part of this implementation).

Comment: The firewall is exactly what is lacking in your setup; the router needs to *route* somewhere packets addresses to those addresses, and since it can't have those addresses directly assigned to its external interface (because they are in a different IP subnet), it needs to send them to some other device. It shouldn't be doing any NAT at all.

Comment: Or are you saying that I would have to create a virtual interface with ip address 72.165.117.130, mark that as the outside interface, and then I could perform the NAT?

Comment: I don't know if your router can receive a packet on one interface, send it to an address on another interface and *then* perform NAT on it to send it out via a *third* interface. But, even if it could, that would be a really messy setup...

Comment: Thank you for the information; it does makes sense to me now.